# Django Channels Not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-channels

I have been following Django channels tutorial, but I am stuck on why my application is not working. Whenever I change the database through the django ORM, I am not getting any updates on my browser.

routing.py

```
from channels import route_class
from values.consumers import Secondmultiplexer

channel_routing = [
    route_class(Secondmultiplexer, path='^/stream2/?$')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from channels.binding.websockets import WebsocketBinding


class SimpleStock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    current_price = models.FloatField(default=0)


class SimpleStockBinding(WebsocketBinding):
    model = SimpleStock
    stream = "stocks"
    fields = ["ticker", "current_price"]

    @classmethod
    def group_names(cls, instance):
        return ["stocks-updates"]

    def has_permission(self, user, action, pk):
        return True
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websockets import WebsocketDemultiplexer

from .models import SimpleStockBinding

class Secondmultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    consumers = {
        "stocks": SimpleStockBinding.consumer,
    }

    groups = ["binding.values"]
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Databinding Example{% endblock %}
{% block header_text %}Databinding Example{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


{% endblock %}

{% block extra_body %}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var second_path = "/stream2/";

            console.log("Connecting to " + second_path);

            var secondWebSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();

            secondWebSocketBridge.connect(second_path);
            secondWebSocketBridge.listen();


            secondWebSocketBridge.demultiplex('stocks',function(payload, streamName) {
                console.log(payload);
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "databinding.settings")
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you have your `asgi` file configured properly?

Comment: I am not getting an error so to speak, I am not getting the console log from within the demultiplex after inserting a new stock

Comment: I'd advise using Channels 2 since Channels 1 is no longer maintained. In Chrome developer tools you can view the raw websocket connection. That way you can see if you are getting the data and the problem is with your frontend code.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the asgiref version

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Try to elaborate what to do and how it helps.